# What control character do I send to the terminal to make it delete a full word at a time?

Tags: terminal

I recently discovered that sending \033[5D and \033[5C sends the character to move a full word at a time, making mac os x terminal almost as awesome as the default ubuntu and debian terminals.

So then, the one thing I'm missing is: the control key to bind option-delete and option-backspace to deletion of full words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select "Preferences..." from the Menu "Terminal"
2. go into "Settings" and select your default window configuration, go into the tab "Keyboard"
3. Have a look at all keybindings, (eg. forward delete is bound to \033[3~ ) and note you can change them by double clicking (thats easier to use than bind in your `~/.bash_profile`).

If you choose to use <kbd>⌥</kbd> as meta-key, <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> will work immediately, though this setup might break special characters you can only input by pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd> together with them (depending on your keyboard layout). If you don´t use that, you can delete by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> and than <kbd>backspace</kbd>.

For forward-deleting a whole word, use either <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or  <kbd>esc</kbd> and than <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will delete the previous word.

Comment: In the bare terminal, yes, but in emacs, it gets caught and has no effect.